# Cannot return the promise correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to call a function in my service. The problem is that after selecting a valid date, I have to return a date.

The promise is never called because I think I return in a wrong way. Can you help me to solve my problem?

This is the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at AgendaController.abrirAgenda

**agenda.controller.js**

```
function abrirAgenda() {
        var fechaLimite = new Date(vm.agendaComplejo.anioHoy, vm.agendaComplejo.mesHoy - 1, vm.agendaComplejo.diaHoy);
        fechaLimite.setDate(fechaLimite.getDate() + 30);
        var fechaSeleccionada = new Date(vm.agendaComplejo.anioSeleccionado, vm.agendaComplejo.mesSeleccionado - 1, vm.agendaComplejo.diaSeleccionado);
        agendaService.abrirAgenda(fechaSeleccionada, fechaLimite)
            .then(prueba);
    }

//prueba
    function prueba(resultado){
        debugger;
    }
```

**agenda.service.js**

```
// abrir la agenda para cambiar de día / mes
    function abrirAgenda(fechaSeleccionada, fechaLimite) {
        debugger;
        var ipObj1 = {
            callback: function (val) {  //Mandatory
                var fecha = new Date(val);
                var dia = fecha.getDate();
                var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1; //Se suma 1 porque el primer mez comienza en 0
                var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
                var fechaDeseada = anio + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
                return fechaDeseada;
            }, 
            inputDate:  fechaSeleccionada,
            //inputDate: new Date(),
            titleLabel: 'Seleccione una fecha',
            setLabel: 'Aceptar',
            todayLabel: 'Hoy',
            closeLabel: 'Cancelar',
            mondayFirst: true,
            from: new Date(2016, 2, 1),
            to: fechaLimite,
            weeksList: ["D", "L", "M", "MIE", "J", "V", "S"],
            monthsList: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
            templateType: 'popup',
            showTodayButton: false,
            dateFormat: 'dd MMMM yyyy',
            closeOnSelect: false
        };
        ionicDatePicker.openDatePicker(ipObj1);
    }
```

I need to return the selected date: `"fechaDeseada"`. I'm trying to use [ionic datepicker](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `abrirAgenda` doesn't return anything, so, it returns `undefined`, hence the error. There's also no hint of any promises in the code at all. Does `ionicDatePicker.openDatePicker` function return a Promise?

Comment: Offtopic but I advise coding in english only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the framework uses promises?  The examples don't show it.

I'd try using the callback object instead, like this:

**agenda.controller.js**

```
function abrirAgenda() {
    //...

    agendaService.abrirAgenda(fechaSeleccionada, fechaLimite, function(val){
            var fecha = new Date(val);
            var dia = fecha.getDate();
            var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1; //Se suma 1 porque el primer mez comienza en 0
            var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
            var fechaDeseada = anio + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;            
            prueba(fechaDeseada)
    })
}
```

**agenda.service.js**

```
function abrirAgenda(fechaSeleccionada, fechaLimite, callback) {
    debugger;
    var ipObj1 = {
        callback: callback, 
        //...
    };
    ionicDatePicker.openDatePicker(ipObj1);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I made a mistake. There is not promise. I need to use callback. Thanks!

Comment: @FederickJons There's no "need" to use callbacks. You *should* use promises. If `openDatePicker` doesn't support promises out of the box, you can always [promisify](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) it.

Answer (score 0):

To return a promise from an API that doesn't return promises, use the [AngularJS $q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
app.service("agendaService", function($q) {
    this.abrirAgenda = abrirAgenda;

    function abrirAgenda(fechaSeleccionada, fechaLimite) {
        //debugger;
        var qFuture = $q.defer();
        var ipObj1 = {
            callback: function (val) {  //Mandatory
                var fechaDeseada = anio + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
                //...
                //return fechaDeseada;
                qFuture.resolve(fechaDeseada);
            }, 
            //...
        };
        ionicDatePicker.openDatePicker(ipObj1);
        return qFuture.promise;
    }
});
```

In the above example, when the Ionic `openDatePicker` method invokes the callback, it resolves the promise created by `$q.defer`.

To use:

```
agendaService.abrirAgenda(fechaSeleccionada, fechaLimite)
    .then(prueba);

//prueba
function prueba(resultado){
    debugger;
};
```

**NOTE:** This only applies to APIs that don't return promises. Services such as `$http`, `$timeout`, `ngResource`, **AngularFire**, etc. already return promise. In those cases there is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer`. Derived promises can be created simply by [Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).